# Unable to generate logs for non Rm commandlets in Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-eventhub

I am able to generate logs in EventHub while using the `New-AzureRmStorageContainer` commandlet but I am unable to generate the same while using `New-AzureStorageContainer`.

I wanted to know how I would be able to do the same for the non-`Rm` commandlets.

Comment: Could you please provide your code which works using New-AzureRmStorageContainer?

Comment: Hey, I'm creating a storage container as follows: `New-AzureRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName rsrcgrp -AccountName storageaccnt -ContainerName
 containername`

Comment: I want to be clear, you just want to create a container with non-rm cmdlet? I saw you mentioned eventhub.

Comment: No Ivan, I can create containers using both commandlets. The only difference is I am able to generate logs for container creation while using the commandlets which are of type `Rm`.

Comment: ok, I will try to use c# code to generate logs to container which is created by non-RM cmdlet. And will update you the next day.

Comment: Thanks for helping out!